# Are all road bike drop handlebars compatible with all shifter/brake levers

Tags: road-bike, compatibility, handlebars, drop-bar, aero-bars

[image]I have a Trek Domane and I want to upgrade the generic basic handlebars with carbon aero handle bars.
I want to make sure they would be compatible with the levers. I was thinking of Easton, Prime Primavera, or Zipp.
I am rocking Shimano levers

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  You talk about drop handlebars in your title, but in the question you ask about converting to aero bars.  These are not the same thing; perhaps you should include a link/photo of the bars you're considering.  (AFAIK, most shifters are fine on pretty much any bar with a normal-sized circular cross-section at the mounting location.)

Comment: added photo to help explanation

Answer (score 3):

Generally yes - the only part of the drop bars that matters to the shifter is the curved part where they clamp on, and whether the bar's hooks allows the shifter to slide on.

There will be small variations in sizes due to the curve-radius of the bars and how it was formed - ie, metals will stretch and deform some giving a slightly ovaloid profile, and carbon fibre ones will probably be much more round in cross section because they are not bent from tube.

---

The other gotcha is the diameter of the center section, to which the stem clamps.  That's not relevant to shifters, but will have to match your existing stem too.   Or consider a replacement stem to match your steerer tube, or even an integrated set of bars/stem for added aero.